# I want to serve static files with permissions logic in my django project

Tags: django

So I've been working on a django project. Its a marketplace platform (two kinds of users - buyer & seller) and when a seller uploads files for a buyer, only those two users should have access to the uploaded files. I'm trying to figure how static files can be served with these permissions.

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I'm using nginx to serve the static files, so is there a way to add permissions logic in django to serve these static files?

Comment: You would have to serve the files through Django and not Nginx if your need to add this kind of logic. Which file storage backend are you using?

Comment: If I serve these files via Django wouldn't that cause performance issues? Infact performance is the whole reason I'd like to use nginx. I haven't changed the storage backend yet so it's the default one that Django provides.

Comment: You could potentially look into using subrequest authentication for your media files https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/. You would have to add a view to your app that validated if a user had permission to access the file they requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of Django terminology first: you're not talking about "static files" (those are the css, js, images and other assets that are part of your source) but about "media files" (user uploaded content).

Now for the technical answer: [use nginx's X-Accel-Redirect feature](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/). This delegates the permissions validation to your Django app, but still let nginx serve the file itself.